# Como generar un if con condiciones vba

Tags: excel, vba

estoy intentando pasar una formula del excel a codigos de VBA pero tiene varias condicinoes y al pasarlo no me ejecuta, he intentado haciendolo con if por separado, pero no me funciona.

```vb
>=SI(O2="D" ; 
SI(P2="EX-AGF" ; 
SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO(DETALLE!J:J ; 
DETALLE!A:A ; 
REVISION!A2 ; 
DETALLE!K:K ; 
"N" ; 
DETALLE!F:F ;
 "<>GDIARIO") ; 
SI(P2="AGF" ; 
SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO(DETALLE!J:J ; 
DETALLE!A:A ; 
REVISION!A2 ; 
DETALLE!K:K;
"S";
DETALLE!F:F;
"<>GDIARIO");
SI(P2="TODOS";
SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO(DETALLE!J:J;
DETALLE!A:A;
REVISION!A2;
DETALLE!F:F;
"<>GDIARIO"))));
0)
```

Esa es la fórmula que estoy intentando dejar en VBA.

Este es el codigo que he estado intetnando, pero son las condiciones lo que no me y ha funcionado, lo que debería pasar es que se sumen unas celdas, dadas las condiciones

```
fx = 2 FilaFormato = Sheets("REVISION").Cells(Row.Count, 15).End(X1UP).Row + 1

Do While Not IsEmpty(Sheets("REVISION").Cells(fx, 15))

Sheets("REVISION").Cells(fx, 23).Activate

If Cells(fx, 15) = "D" Then

If Cells(fx, 16) = "EX-AGF" Then

Sheets("Formato").Cells(FilaFormato, 23) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Sheets("DETALLE").Range("J:J"), Sheets("DETALLE").Range("A:A"), Sheets("REVISION").Cells(fx, 1), Sheets("DETALLE").Range("K:K") = "N", Sheets("DETALLE").Range("F:F") <> "GDIARIO")

ElseIf Cells(fx, 16) = "AGF" Then

Sheets("Formato").Cells(FilaFormato, 23) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Sheets("DETALLE").Range("J:J"), Sheets("DETALLE").Range("A:A"), Sheets("REVISION").Cells(fx, 1), Sheets("DETALLE").Range("K:K") = "S", Sheets("DETALLE").Range("F:F") <> "GDIARIO")

ElseIf Cells(fx, 16) = "TODOS" Then

Sheets("Formato").Cells(FilaFormato, 23) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Sheets("DETALLE").Range("J:J"), Sheets("DETALLE").Range("A:A"), Sheets("REVISION").Cells(fx, 1), Sheets("DETALLE").Range("F:F") <> "GDIARIO")

End If End If Loop
```

espero alguien pueda ayudarme.

Comment: Y cuál es el código VBA que estás probando? QUé significa que "no me funciona"? QUé error sale? Con qué datos pruebas esa fórmula y qué debería pasar?

Comment: Abajo sólo van los intentos de respuesta. Puedes [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/478095/edit) tu pregunta todas las veces que sea necesario para añadir la info relevante o las aclaraciones que te pidan. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Acabo de pasar tu no-respuesta a la pregunta para ayudarte a que te respondan rápido. Por favor, borra la no-respuesta :)

Comment: Mira [Instrucción Select Case](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/select-case-statement). Creo que te puede venir muy bien.

Comment: Deberías de ser un poco más explícito. Intenta explicar que es lo que pretendes. que celdas deseas seleccionar y con que propósito. Veo varios errores en tu código, sobre todo a la hora de seleccionar las celdas. Intenta explicar bien lo que pretendes a ver si podemos ayudarte. Un saludo